# What is a function that returns a promise called?

Tags: javascript, promise

What do you call a function which returns a promise?

*This is not the start of a joke*

Comment: "A function that returns a promise."

Comment: An asynchronous function.

Comment: :) yip. Looking for something specifically relating to the creation of promises.

Comment: "Promiser" seems the most succinct.

Comment: BTW, if no-one has already coined this term in this context, I claim ownership :)

Comment: haha *hits wikipedia*

Comment: Maybe a 'pledge'? Pledger? Giver?

Comment: Not sure why the vote to close. No reason why this would not be answered with "facts, references, or specific expertise".

Comment: @Ross the person voted to close was for opinion based answer which in a way it is and it border lines on programming since you are just asking for a word. I think promiser will do, http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Promiser

Comment: @Huangism true, it could be opinion based. But taking the [Clojure API](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/) most of the terms there are computer science based. So why would there not be an 'academically' relevant term.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the javascript community I've seen a function that returns a promise called being "thenable" enough times that I think "**thenable**" when I'm coding. It's a **thenable function**.

I like this name for a number of reasons:

1) Thenable describes the functional behaviour. If it returns a promise, you can call "then" on it.

2) **It's unique.** Promises aren't exactly monadic, so monad isn't appropriate. "Async" is more of a super class of functions and doesn't help describe the nature of a Promise. But "thenable" is uniquely Promisely.

3) I also like that it's not repeating Promise everywhere, (Promissory, Promisified, Promise Function, etc.) which is approaching a circular definition IMO. Being able to google one word which has one specific meaning is really nice.

Comment: This definition is not widely used by the community at all. `thennable` is just a term the promises/a+ spec uses internally. I've literally never seen it used anywhere outside of some of my own answers here.

Comment: Moreover, based on the terminology defined - a thennable function is a function that has a `then` method.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I can't gauge how widespread the use of the term is. I just know I learned it from others while learning about Promises, and it works for me. I agree with you, the term is contingent upon the function actually having a `then` method.

Comment: @ChristianDavis I think the spelling is wrong. It should be 'thenable' with one _n_. See: https://promisesaplus.com/

Comment: Right, so we are in agreement that a "thenable function" is a function that has a `then` method. A concept that was actually discussed by the way recently. What it doesn't mean is "a function that returns a promise".  @Ross The term means something different there.

Answer (score 8):

#### Well...

The current answers aren't really correct. The truth of the matter is **there is no short clever name for "function that returns a promise"** that is in the consensus of the JS community.

#### In JavaScript

The spec doesn't name them in a special way, no documentation of any popular library names them in a special way. The promises specification does not name them in any special way.

#### The origin of promises

From the other hand, if we check the literature branch originating from [Liskov and Shrira](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/context/84982/0), they don't, and neither do [Bogle](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-624.pdf) nor [Zondervan](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-658.pdf) use any term other than "getting a promise" or "getting the future" for it (they do use `claim` for extracting the value).

If we check [Mark Miller's work](http://www.erights.org/talks/thesis/markm-thesis.pdf) he does not use any terms for it either.

#### Other languages

In other languages things don't fare better. C# has no special name for methods that return `Task`s (its promises). It does have "async functions" for functions that return async/await but that's only a strict subset. No special name in Scala, no special name in Python, no special name in Java and so on. The only thing *close* was parse's Android API naming their promises' `then` callbacks `Continuation` but that's hardly meaningful in this context.

#### Name suggestions

If it makes you feel any better - we don't have a name for something that returns an array either.

- **"Monadic functions"** - Lots of functions can return monads that are not promises, moreover promises aren't really monads - they don't *actually* conform in their current form to monad laws nor does `then` make a valid `bind`. More importantly, very few JS developers even know what monads are and even fewer care.
- **"async function"** - this might hold when (and if! it's not 100% sure now) the `async` modifier is added to the language. Right now and probably event then a lot of people consider things like `setTimeout` or `fs.openFile` to be async functions.
- **"Kleisli Arrows"** - I took a type theory course and it covered this topic and I don't think me or any other students would call a function that returns a monad a Kleisli arrow. For one thing because it's an [Arrow](https://wiki.haskell.org/Arrow_tutorial) (yes yes, arrows are functions I get it).

#### Conclusion

To conclude, the people who invented promises, the people who specified them for JavaScript, the people who put that spec in writing, the spec itself, the promise libraries, the libraries written with those and the average user don't have any special name for it.

I think we can stick to **A function that returns a promise**.

If it makes you feel any better - we don't name "functions that return an int" either :)

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, there are no individual words to describe functions that return a particular type. They are generally called "a function that returns a *<Type>*".

For example:

- `foo()` is a function that returns a *String*
- `bar()` is a function that returns a *Number*
- `baz()` is a function that returns a *Promise*

In this context, `Promise` is being used similar to how an interface would in a strongly typed language.

Another example of a generic type being used would be

- `fizz()` is a function that returns a *collection*

---

That's not to say that there can't be a word with a definition of "a function that returns a *Promise*", but there's no commonly used jargon to describe this.

"deferred function" is sometimes used to describe a function that returns promises or promise-like objects (i.e. jQuery's Deferred Object).

Functions that return promises can also be described by other more general words (in much the same way that a square can be described as a rectangle, parallelogram, rhombus, or quadrilateral).

- Promises are monads, so they can be described as "monadic".
- Promises are asynchronous, so functions that utilize them can be described as asynchronous as well.

---

Personally, I'd go with "promissory functions", as "promissory" means:

> conveying or implying a promise

and I like the idea that the return value of such a function is "conveying a promise".

Answer (score 2):

We call them *asynchronous functions*. Even if the function does nothing asynchronous itself, it at least returns a promise - an asynchronous value.

You can shorten that to *async function*, although that term is also used for the ES7 syntactic notation `async function` that creates functions which return promises implicitly (whose code can use `await`).

If you want to think of the type of functions that return monads (which promises are), you can call them [*Kleisli arrows*](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/06/monads-kleisli-arrows-comonads-and.html). But you did ask a [javascript] question, not a [type-theory] one, did you?

Comment: You know, I have been using Haskell for more than a year now and I still have to learn about kleisli categories, yonedas, etc. I just recently learned about f-algebras and f-coalgebras. I wish they would teach us Category Theory in college. =(

Answer (score 1):

Technically, a [promise is a monad](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2011/03/11/promises-are-the-monad-of-asynchronous-programming/). Hence, a function that returns a promise is a [monadic function](http://www.codejury.com/making-sense-of-monadic-functions/).

Comment: And let's call functions that return values from the `Promise` monad "*promising functions*", shouldn't we?

Comment: @Bergi What's in a name? If this really hurts your feelings then I wouldn't mind deleting it. Should I?

Comment: No, no, *monadic* as an adjective is fine. I just was trying to make a joke on "promising" :-)

Comment: Haha. Alright. Text is such an impersonal medium. There's no way to communicate stress. Hence, it's difficult to decipher whether you are frustrated or cheerful. =P

Comment: Anyway, if ES7 will create new syntax for `async function` then I guess it makes sense to call them "asynchronous functions" (as in the fully explicit version of an `async function`). ;)

Comment: Just don't expect people to understand waht you're saying when you use that term :D

Comment: Are promises actually monads? They're quite close to monads, but I'm not sure if they actually fulfil the requirements of one.